# How to rotate Flutter Map markers to direction when the driver is moving with the package flutter_map?

Tags: flutter, dart

[Image in the map but not going true the direction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vT4CI.png)
[My code in FlutterMap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZLJEK.png)

Please can someone help me with a solution to get the car to follow the road

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a list of coordinates (LatLng), this is my implementation:

```
 double getHeading(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2) {
    var lat1rad = lat1 * pi / 180;
    var lat2rad = lat2 * pi / 180;
    var dLon = (lon2 - lon1) * pi / 180;
    
    var y = sin(dLon) * cos(lat2);
    var x = cos(lat1rad) * sin(lat2rad) -
            sin(lat1rad) * cos(lat2rad) * cos(dLon);
    
    var brng = atan2(y, x);
    
    return (((brng * 180 / pi) + 360) % 360);
}

rotation = getHeading(lastPoint.lat, lastPoint.lon, actual.lat, actual.lon);
    
setState(() {
   _mapController.rotate(-rotation);  
})
```